# How to escape regex in java in order to make them work properly?

Tags: java, android, regex

Actually I am not an expert in regex ,I've always copied and pasted them... Right now I am finishing an android application and I needed to check wether the input string from an autocompleteTextView was matching the multiple and most common known forms of url and so I found out this regex:

```
/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/
```

, that after escaping it like this:

```
/^(https?:\\/\\/)?([\\da-z\\.-]+)\\.([a-z\\.]{2,6})([\\/\\w \\.-]*)*\\/?$/
```

was not working as it should… Am I escaping it wrong, or it's something else ?

Comment: Why did you entered the extra `\` so that it looked like `\\`? This will make regex understand it as a literal \ and will make `\/` that was understood as `/` be understood as something else…

Comment: Are you validating one url of multiple url with this regex at the same time?

Comment: Just one at the time.. The user chose the url to search and the app searches it after checking it whit this regex.. Initially I used to create a new Url object from the string and if I wasn't trowed an exception for wrong url the research could have been done... but the only problem with that was that every time I had to start the url with http or https...

Comment: I get it. What kind of behavior is this regex giving you. Not validating correct urls or validating incorrect urls?

Comment: Sorry I meant not validating anything..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex looks like it was written for JavaScript.  Since Java doesn't support regex literals (e.g. `/regex/`), you have to write yours as a Java string literal.  You're halfway there already with the double escapes; now you need to replace the regex delimiters with quotes:

```
"^(https?:\\/\\/)?([\\da-z\\.-]+)\\.([a-z\\.]{2,6})([\\/\\w \\.-]*)*\\/?$"
```

That should work fine, but many of those escapes aren't needed.  Specifically, the slashes (`/`) aren't special because you're not using them as delimiters any more, and the dot isn't special when it's in a character class (i.e., inside the square brackets).  Here's the tidied version:

```
"^(https?://)?([\\da-z.-]+)\\.([a-z.]{2,6})([/\\w .-]*)*/?$"
```

Note that I'm only talking about the *syntax* of your regex, not its correctness.  Validating URL's with a regex has been the subject of many heated discussions, and I don't want to start another one.

Comment: There is another bigger problem with this regex. It suffers badly from catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: So it does, and that would be a real problem if we were searching for URLs in a large document, but we're validating them as standalone strings.

Comment: Try this in your browser `/^(https?:\/\/)?([\da-z\.-]+)\.([a-z\.]{2,6})([\/\w \.-]*)*\/?$/.test("https://...............asia........./.......%")`. The easiest fix is to change `([\/\w \.-]*)*` to `[\/\w \.-]*`. Anyway, as you said, the regex is terrible at recognizing valid addresses.